# db2 sqlstate 42972 error

Tags: java, sql, db2

I am getting this error when I am trying to execute this sql query

```
INSERT INTO
            AGG_QUALITY
    SELECT
            QIF.DATEDM_ID, 
            'Status' AS BREAKDOWN_TYPE, 
            HCR.VALUE, 
            QIF.SCANDEFINITION_ID, 
            QIF.QUALITYISSUE_VALUE, 
            COUNT(QIF.QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID), 
            COUNT(QRF.QUALITYRESOLUTIONFACT_ID)

    FROM
            QUALITYISSUEFACT QIF,
            HUBCODERECORD HCR,
            ITEMSTATUS ITS
    LEFT JOIN
            QUALITYRESOLUTIONFACT QRF
    ON
            QIF.QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID = QRF.QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID
    WHERE
            QIF.DATEDM_ID > startDateDMId 
            AND     QIF.DATEDM_ID <= endDateDMId    
            AND HCR.CODE = ITS.H_STATUS_TYPE
            AND QIF.DIMENSION_ROM_PK = ITS.ITEMMASTER_ID
    GROUP BY
            QIF.DATEDM_ID, HCR.VALUE, QIF.SCANDEFINITION_ID, QIF.QUALITYISSUE_VALUE
    ;
```

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0338N  An ON clause associated with a JOIN operator or in a MERGE statement 
is not valid.  LINE NUMBER=31.  SQLSTATE=42972

Comment: Don't archaic implicit joins with clean modern `join` syntax.  That will probably fix your problem.  A simple rule:  just say "No" to commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Can you confirm that the column `QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID` exists in both `QUALITYISSUEFACT` and `QUALITYRESOULTIONFACT` tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below with inner joins:

```
INSERT INTO
            AGG_QUALITY
    SELECT
            QIF.DATEDM_ID, 
            'Status' AS BREAKDOWN_TYPE, 
            HCR.VALUE, 
            QIF.SCANDEFINITION_ID, 
            QIF.QUALITYISSUE_VALUE, 
            COUNT(QIF.QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID), 
            COUNT(QRF.QUALITYRESOLUTIONFACT_ID)

    FROM
            QUALITYISSUEFACT QIF
            INNER JOIN
            HUBCODERECORD HCR
            ON QIF.DIMENSION_ROM_PK = ITS.ITEMMASTER_ID
            INNER JOIN
            ITEMSTATUS ITS
            ON QIF.DIMENSION_ROM_PK = ITS.ITEMMASTER_ID
    LEFT JOIN
            QUALITYRESOLUTIONFACT QRF
    ON
            QIF.QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID = QRF.QUALITYISSUEFACT_ID
    WHERE
            QIF.DATEDM_ID > startDateDMId 
            AND     QIF.DATEDM_ID <= endDateDMId    
    GROUP BY
            QIF.DATEDM_ID, HCR.VALUE, QIF.SCANDEFINITION_ID, QIF.QUALITYISSUE_VALUE
    ;
```

see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error here. (note, my Table1 has NO rows)

On my side I could solve it by changing the additional (comma separated) table2 to a REAL inner join.

Example from

```
select xxx from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 
where (t2.col1 = t1.col1) and (t1.col2 = "whatever")
```

to

```
select xxx from Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t2.col1 = t1.col1)
where (t1.col2 = "whatever")
```

Hope this helps someone else.
(problem occured on DB2 9.7)